# How to hide C# unit tests?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, vstest

For quick experiments, I prefer to use "unit tests" *–i.e. annotating one (or more) method with [`[TestMethod]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testmethodattribute.aspx)–* over creating a tiny project with a `Main` method.

A test method has some advantages over a tiny project:

- it is quicker to write a method and annotate it with [`[TestMethod]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testmethodattribute.aspx) than to create a new project;
- the test method can use facilities provides by [the visual studio test tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.aspx) such as test fixtures shared with similar experiments (via [`[TestInitialize]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute.aspx));
- the method can be executed by right clicking and selecting "Run test" (in visual studio 2015);
  and,
- using [`Assert()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.aspx) instead of inspecting a value via the debugger or via [`Console.WriteLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) automatically documents the intent and the results of the experiment and makes it repeatable without manual intervention.

A problem is that these experiments show up in the visual studio test explorer, this causes clutter and makes it difficult to distinguish real unit tests from experiments.  *(I'm not using any other testing reporting tools, CI, etc., but I assume that the problem would occur there as well.)*

Is there a way to have the advantages of using [`[TestMethod]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testmethodattribute.aspx) for experiments and avoid the clutter that it causes at the same time?

I tried the following to solve this problem:

- Have the [`[TestClass]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testclassattribute.aspx) and the [`[TestMethod]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testmethodattribute.aspx) attributes as comments and uncomment them when you want to run the experiment.

  This is what I currently do.  It works, but running an experiment is somewhat cumbersome.
- Use [`[Ignore]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.ignoreattribute.aspx) attribute.

  Clutters the test explorer view with ignored tests and requires commenting out the [`[Ignore]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.ignoreattribute.aspx) attribute to run the test.
- Put experiments in different project; as suggested by [Veverke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1219280/veverke) or annotate the test with a [`[TestCategory]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcategoryattribute.aspx) attribute as suggested by [C Sharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1487681/c-sharper).

  The visual studio test explorer can group tests by either class, duration, outcome, traits, project.  To avoid the clutter: Choosing **traits** allows to keep the tree of tests annotated with [`[TestCategory("Experiments")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcategoryattribute.aspx) closed or choosing **projects** allows keeping the "experiments.proj" tree closed.

  When using the grouping to distinguish experiments from tests, the other groupings in the test explorer cannot be used.

## TL;DR

How to write experiments (using visual studio unit tests) without the experiments cluttering the reports about real unit tests?

Comment: 404 - File or directory not found.

Comment: Well no not really. You are using a feature that is not intended for this type of use. Have you looked into LinqPad for writing 'experiment' code?

Comment: Does the test explorer separates tests from different projects ? If so, you could create a separate Unit Test project for your experiments.

Comment: @Veverke the test explorer can separate tests from different projects; tried it out your idea, it works, added it to the tried solutions in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining the answers:

1. Do you *REALLY* want to abuse unit tests as experiments? <sup>(comment by [Jamie Rees](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3329836/jamie-rees) and in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32326204/814206) by [C Sharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1487681/c-sharper))</sup>

   Perhaps Linqpad ([https://www.linqpad.net/]) or something similar is better for experiments.
2. If you want to abuse unit tests, mark each experiment method with a [`[TestCategory]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcategoryattribute.aspx).  This allows grouping the experiments in the test explorer and selecting which tests to run.<sup>(From [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32326204/814206) by [C Sharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1487681/c-sharper))</sup>
3. Use a build configuration to define a conditional compilation symbol, for example `EXPERIMENTS`.  Use `#if EXPERIMENTS` to enable or disable the experiments.  Use a solution build configuration to be able to enable or disable the experiments from the toolbar.(From [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32327331/814206) by [Kasper van den Berg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/814206/kasper-van-den-berg)

Example:

```
#if EXPERIMENTS
[TestClass]
public class MyExperiment1
{
    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Experiment")]
    public void Method1()
    {
        …
    }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you misuse Unit Tests for something for which it was not intended.
But the only solution that comes in my mind is to use `[TestCategory]` attribute to control when a test runs and in which list it should be.

```
[TestMethod(), TestCategory("Nightly"), TestCategory("Weekly"), TestCategory("ShoppingCart")]
public void DebitTest()
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Experiments can be disabled via an ifdef, e.g.:

```
#if EXPERIMENTS
[TestClass]
public class MyExperiment1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Method1()
    {
        …
    }
}
#endif
```

To enable the experiment add `#define EXPERMIMENTS` as first line the file; however, this is still cumbersome.  The conditional compilation symbol (`EXPERIMENTS`) can also be defined via project properties.  To improve on this, create an build configuration and a solution configuration and define the conditional compilation symbols only for the build configuration.